# Laravel Eloquent Getting children of children via model relqtionships

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to directly edit my Kodi MySQL DB and build a tool to fix some scraping errors that have always been not quite right.

the relationship of tables is
tvshow -> episode -> file

So I'm able to so far (after creating models for these tables)

1. List all shows
2. view specific show and list all episodes
3. show file entry for that episode.

What I'm trying to do is list all files that belong to the show, via a dropdown. ( as I need to change them )

So I need to use the TVShow model to get all epiodoes that have an idShow entry.. AND then get all the files based on the episode table. I know that Eloquent can handle this typically, but I've only ever used my own table structure, never one like this.. so I think my issue is over riding key names etc...

the key column names are:

idShow

idEpisode

idFile

(Where that SAME name is used as the primary key on the parent table AND the mapping ID in the child table)

Anyhoo, here's my models..

Any ideas?

TVShow

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent as Model;

class TvShow extends Model
{

    public $table = 'tvshow';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idShow';

    public function episodes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Episode::class, 'idShow');
    }

}
```

Episode

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent as Model;

class Episode extends Model
{

    public $table = 'episode';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idEpisode';

    public function tvshow()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(TvShow::class, 'idShow', 'idShow');
    }

    public function season()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Season::class, 'idShow', 'idShow')->where('season', '>=', 0)->where('idSeason', $this->idSeason);
    }

    public function file()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(File::class, 'idFile', 'idFile');
    }

    public function files()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(File::class, 'idFile', 'idShow');
    }

}
```

File

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent as Model;

class File extends Model
{

    public $table = 'files';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idFile';

    public function episode()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Episode::class, 'idFile', 'idFile');
    }

}
```

I'm calling this in my Controller...

```
TvShow::with('episodes.files')->get();
```

I'm getting ALL shows as a list..?

Comment: Use a has many through relationship. See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: hasMany... on Episode model for the files method? cause I have that.. so where did you mean please? cheers for quick reply though!!

Comment: Not `hasMany` but `hasManyThrough`. I've included an example in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hasManyThrough relationship will work. Add this to your `TvShow` model.

```
public function files()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Episode::class, File::class);
}
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: Ooo, my keys are wrong, but the SQL that generated (after I tweaked) worked great!!

Going to learn hasManyThroughvia docs now.. CHEERS!!!!